# GL$_2(\mathbb{Q}) Z_{\mathbb{R}}$ closed in GL$_2(\mathbb{A})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am struggling with the following subgroups of GL$_2(\mathbb{A})$ where $\mathbb{A}$ is (the topological ring of) Adeles over $\mathbb{Q}$:

$$G_\mathbb{Q} := \iota(\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})) $$
where
$$\iota : \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}) \to \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{A})
, ~~~\iota(y) = (y,y,...|y)$$
and
$$Z_{\mathbb{R}} = \{(id, id, ...| r ~id) : r \in \mathbb{R}^\times \}$$
the notation being to be read as follows: I write $g = (\gamma, g)$ for an element $g$ of GL$_2(\mathbb{A})$ for $\gamma \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_{\text{fin}})$, the finite part of the adeles, i.e.
$$\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_{\text{fin}}) = \widehat{\prod}_{p \in \mathbb{P}}^{\text{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)} \text{GL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$$
carries the topology of restricted rectangles (see below), $\mathbb{P} = \{2,3,5,...\}$ is the set of (finite) primes, and $g \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

The question is the following:

---

Is $G_\mathbb{Q} Z_\mathbb{R}$ closed in GL$_2(\mathbb{A})$?

---

++++++++++ EDIT: ++++++++++++

Ok, one possible answer is that
$$\omega : G_\mathbf{Q} Z_{\mathbf{R}}\backslash \text{GL}_2(\mathbf{A}) \to \tilde{G_\mathbb{Q}} \backslash \text{GL}_2^1(\mathbb{A}), ~~~ \omega(G_\mathbf{Q} Z_{\mathbf{R}} g) = \tilde{G_\mathbb{Q}} g$$

is a homemorphism. Now $G_\mathbb{Q}$ is discrete in GL$_2(\mathbb{A})$, so it is closed. Hence, so is $\tilde{G_\mathbb{Q}}$. As generally, for every LCH group $G$ and a subgroup $H$, $H\backslash G$ is an LCH space iff. H is closed, $G_\mathbf{Q} Z_{\mathbf{R}}\backslash \text{GL}_2(\mathbf{A})$ is hausdroffian and thus,  $G_\mathbf{Q} Z_{\mathbf{R}}$ is closed... but there must be a better way to see this :(

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

- Additional information:

GL$_n2(\mathbb{A})$ carries the topology of restricted rectangles meaning that a set is open iff. it it can be written as a union over so-called restricted rectangles, that is sets of the form

$$U = \prod_{p \in E} U_p \times \prod_{p \notin E} \text{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p) \times U_\infty$$

where $E$ is a finite set of prime numbers and $U_p \subset \text{GL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ is open and $U_\infty \subset \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is open.

- That much I know

[*] $G_\mathbb{Q}$ is discrete (hence closed) in GL$_2(\mathbb{A})$

[*] $Z_{\mathbb{R}}$ is closed as it it the preimage of the projection to the $\infty$ part of the closed set $\begin{pmatrix} * & 0 \\ 0 & *\end{pmatrix}$ in GL$_2(\mathbb{R})$.

[*] In general, the product of two closed subgroups is not closed, not even when it makes sense to consider their product (i.e. when one normalizes the other so that their product becomes a subgroup), so it must be something related to the special structure...

Thanks in advance,

FW